# Why Java is not working in cmd nor giving any error?

Tags: java, windows, terminal

When I try to use java in cmd or powershell it doesn't do anything (it doesn't give me an error so it shoudn't be an environment variable issue).

For example both `C:\Users\andre>java --version` and `C:\Users\andre>java SomeClass` don't give any response (see the following screenshot)

[image: here's a screenshot]

`javac` works fine and i have already reinstalled jdk 16. The PATH variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`, anyway even if I open the terminal in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin` I get the same result.

Comment: One dash (not two). `java -version` The `JAVA_HOME` should be set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1` and the `PATH` should include `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. I'm not sure why you set the `PATH` variable as you have.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Recent Java versions (I believe since Java 9) also support `java --version`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, seconding this. I just checked the two dashes and it works too.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Cool. So it's just a PATH issue.

Comment: Does file `java.exe` exist in folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin`? What is the output of command `where java`? Did you try searching for file `java.exe`? Is JDK 16 the only java version you have installed? Some software products have an embedded JDK. Perhaps you have such a software product installed? (For example Oracle client.)

Comment: your PATH variable is set Incorrect (it is set to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath") it should be "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin".

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer when you install Oracle's [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html), it edits the `PATH` environment variable and adds the location `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`.

Comment: @Abra `java.exe` exists in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin` (it's also the output of `where java`, and the PATH variable ) , I don't think i have another JDK installed. Now that i have changed the PATH variable to the correct value the only thing that has changed is that `C:\Users\andre>java --version` ask to allow changes to the computer and then does nothing as always.

Answer (score -2):

Windows app store sets one more variable as default. So, set this to path variable at the start instaed of end.
And also you can check that using command "where java"

Comment: Clearly, the issue is unrelated to the %PATH% environment variable.

Comment: Why don't the person who posted decide that? And for you, it is issue in detecting java then why not it is related to path? You can see that "Clearly"

Answer (score -2):

Try running command `javap`
If it is working, then everything is good to go.
If not, try resetting your env path to `programfiles/java/jdk/bin`

Happy Coding

Comment: Why would any of that help?